# Linux: How to calculate/find the slackspace of a file?

Tags: linux, sparse-files

How would I go about finding the slackspace of a file, for instance.

```
fls -o 63 /images/diskimg.dd 
istat -o 63 /images/diskimg.dd 31
icat -o 63 /images/diskimg.dd | xxd | less
```

In which of these commands would I use to find the slackspace? Or is there another? How would I also go about finding information that could be stored in the slackspace?

I found out that using the -s option will allow me to look through the slackspace of the file with the icat command, still not sure to go about calulculating the slackspace size, don't fancy adding it up with icat.

Comment: You may want to close your [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862674/linux-how-to-calculate-find-the-slackspace-of-a-file)

Comment: Deleted it. Hoped someone from SO would know.

Answer (score 2):

The "slackspace" you're referring to is often called sparse space within a file. You can use the `ls` & `du` commands to detect how much sparse space a give file is consuming.

*excerpt from [Wikipedia's Sparse File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)*

> #### Detection
>
> The `-s` option of the `ls` command shows the occupied space in blocks, and `-k` the apparent size in blocks too:
>
> ```
>   $ ls -lks sparse-file
> ```
>
> `-h` can be used to print both in human readable format.
>
> Alternatively, the du command prints the occupied space, while `ls` prints the apparent size. The option `--block-size=1` prints the occupied space in bytes instead of blocks, so that it can be compared to the `ls` output:
>
> ```
>   $ du --block-size=1 sparse-file
>   $ ls -l sparse-file
> ```

#### Example

First create a sparse file:

```
$ truncate -s 5M sparsy
```

Now check it out:

```
$ ls -lks sparsy 
0 -rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 5242880 Apr  4 09:18 sparsy

$ ls -l sparsy 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 5242880 Apr  4 09:18 sparsy
```

**NOTE:** The first column in the output from `ls -lks sparsy` is showing a `0`. This means the file `sparsy` is 100% sparse, it's contains no actual blocks of data, just sparse data.

The `du` command shows the same thing:

```
$ du --block-size=1 sparsy 
0   sparsy
```

With a file that's not sparse we'd see this:

```
$ seq 1000 > non-sparsy
```

Now when we check it using `ls`:

```
$ ls -lks non-sparsy 
4 -rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 3893 Apr  4 09:27 non-sparsy
```

We see that's consuming 4 blocks of space. Using `du` shows the same thing:

```
$ du --block-size=1 non-sparsy 
4096    non-sparsy
```

Comment: `stat --printf "%s %b*%B" file` can give you the size and the number of blocks and block size in the one output.

Comment: @mtm - thanks that's basically a condensed version of `ls -lks <file>`.